# AngularJS : How to use ngRepeat with expandable row

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, expand

I have a table database ' PARAMETER ' with 4 column : 'name','description','group' and 'value'. And i want to display the content of this table grouped by ' group' ie : initially, when the table is displayed, just a list of groups will be shown, and after clicking on one of them, there is a list of parameters for that specific group. I proceed like below :

```
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <div>#</div>
                <div>Param Group</div>
            </div>

            <div ng-repeat="param in paramsServer | unique:'paramServerGroup'">
                <div class="row panel panel-body">
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <div class="handpointer glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" data-ng-click="collapse($event);getParamsByGroup(param.paramServerGroup)" data-target="#view_{{param.paramServerGroup}}" data-toggle="collapse" 
                             aria-expanded="false">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12" data-ng-bind="param.paramServerGroup"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse" id="view_{{param.paramServerGroup}}">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1">
                        <table class="table-condensed responsive-table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr class="row">
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody ng-repeat="pGroup in paramsServerGroup">
                            <tr class="row" >
                                <td data-ng-bind="pGroup.paramServerName"></td>
                                <td data-ng-bind="pGroup.paramServerDescription"></td>
                                <td data-ng-bind="pGroup.paramServerValue"></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my controller :

```
$scope.paramsServer = [];
    $scope.paramsServerGroup = [];       

    $http.get("/paramsServer")
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.paramsServer = data;
        });


    $scope.getParamsByGroup = function (group){
        $http.get('/paramsServerByGroup?paramServerGroup='+group)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.paramsServerGroup = data;

        });
    }
```

When i expand a row of group, it works : i have a list of parameters specific to the group ( let's say the first row for instance ). But when i try to expand the second row of group( without collapsing the first one ) the first list of parameters takes content of the newly expanded row. So i ended up with duplicate list of params for two differents group.  The same thing if i expand a third row etc etc ..

Any clue ?

Comment: It would appear that every time you click a row you are refreshing the "paramsServerGroup" array. That array is bound to the ng-repeat for the tbody parameters. So you are effectively changing the model and the view   tbody elements bound to that array within all the div repeats will refresh.

Comment: Yeah thats it. But how can i overcome this issue ? Collapse other rows when expand a row  ? But i still look for other solution that keep all rows expanded..